# Can I use my old Sony Camera's Night Shot to detect shorts?

Tags: infrared, camera, image-sensor, thermal-camera

I have an old Sony TRV-14 with a built-in night shot mode for shooting videos in the dark. It is my understanding it works by using sensing infrared radiation which is also how thermal imaging cameras work. Unlike thermal imaging cameras, the images produces by my camera are in gray scale instead of color.

Is it possible to use my camera in some capacity for detecting shorts or overheating components? I figure hot areas would appear lighter and the cooler areas would appear darker. Am I correct?

Comment: One alternative to that is to spray isopropyl alcohol on the board and carefully watching were it evaporates first.

Comment: Yeah, that and the rosin fumes, but alcohol required no cleanup, but harder to detect. Sadly, the easiest way is always the best way.

Comment: With the influx of cheap IR cameras flooding the marketplace, it may be time to just buy a dedicated tool.  Perhaps a gift this season for yourself.

Comment: @rdtsc  Do tell. Where?  They're certainly cheaper than in the past, but they're still in the $200 range.

Comment: Near IR is not thermal (long) IR.

Comment: Thermal cameras use the band of IR from about 7000 to 12000 nm, which corresponds to temperatures at and around room temperature. The IR that this camera senses is probably NIR in the 700-1400 nm range. That corresponds to temperatures well over 2000 K. If your short is emitting significant amounts of NIR, you will know it without needing a thermal camera.

Comment: You cannot ask about detecting hot zones without defining what "hot" means to you. And if you have some temperature range in mind what is preventing you from pointing camera to some hot object (e.g. a cup of tea) and seeing for yourself if you can tell the difference?  Camera too far away? Then the answer has no value to you.  And the addition of "hypothetical circuitry" into conversation makes the question completely different. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @All - *Please be nice* and comply with the site's [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) (CoC) in everything you write. Nothing snarky / sarcastic / condescending (or worse). Some comments here were deleted after being flagged (and others were removed / edited as obsolete or which referred to now-deleted comments). [Polite constructive criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) is allowed in comments - with the emphasis on *polite* & *constructive*. Also please check especially that a comment still complies with the CoC, if it includes the words "you" or "your". Thanks.

Comment: @Maple  What does hot mean to me?  I obviously asked about short circuits or overheating components. How specific do you want me to be? So only if something doesn't pass your units tests,  it doesn't deserve the dignity of a response?  How dare you tell me whether an answer has value to me or not? I find that extremely arrogant!  What other reason would there be for my question and why do you care?

Comment: As an educator I often have students come to me asking if it would work to do some thing or another. My answer, which I don't consider to be snarky at all, but rather helpful, is "why not try it and then tell the rest of us how it works."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thermal radiation is still an electromagnetic radiation and the wavelength range of thermal radiation covers the IR area.

Your camera's sensor might be able to pick up IR signals just like an I² NV (Infrared-Illuminated Night Vision) so you would expect to detect (or distinguish) heat radiation. However, due to the limitations of your camera's sensor (sensitivity, contrast etc) it's unlikely possible.

> Unlike thermal imaging cameras, the images produces by my camera are in gray scale instead of color.

That's because thermal cameras have special sensors and these cameras **process** the incoming signals from those sensors to generate the heat difference maps.

**Here's a practical test:** A human body generates and radiates its own heat and it's not really low. If your camera can visualize this then yes, you can use your camera for heat detection.

Maybe, your camera can be used to detect very high temperatures such as 200+ °C.

Comment: Thanks. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 10):

No, the wavelengths of IR that your camera senses are much different than those emitted by warm objects.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to use my camera in some capacity for detecting shorts
> or overheating components?

Elliot Alderson gives a terse, decent answer. Here are alternative methods...

Your skin is a [good heat sensor](https://explorable.com/skin-senses-temperature). I find my upper lip -to- nose is good at locating a small heat radiator, held close but not touching.

Shorts generally have small resistance, in which case they don't radiate heat. You should use a different technique to find shorts:

Shorts may cause high current flow. It is often possible to trace this current flow with a sensitive **voltmeter**. If two probes of the voltmeter are placed some distance apart along a suspect wire or printed circuit trace that carries current, a voltage drop is measured. Move along the trace - where the voltage drop is near zero, current has taken a different path.

Comment: Thanks!  I had a duh moment after reading your answer. As a newbie, I fell for the gimmickry of FLIR cameras when practical troubleshooting can be used instead. I wish I had a good resource I could use for general troubleshooting techniques and procedures.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use FLIR ONE Thermal Imager for Android.

It's a low cost optical system for smartphones with USB Type C connector.

It's made by FLIR which is an excellent and reliable American manufacturer and it costs less than 200 USD.

[image]